# Filter a value from a JSON object using Scala

Tags: json, scala

I need to filter a value for this name/value pair ("seq":15) in my JSON object using Scala.
Following is the link for my JSON object.

http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=23188a59d8a10673bcfb632bc6337173

Following is the function I have used :

```
  def wsResponseToValidJsonString(resp: String): String = {
println("This is response :" + resp) // prints Response message in JSON format

//get latest seq number
if (resp.contains("seq")) {
  println("seq contains..") //prints the JSON response
  val regSeq = new Regex(""".*?changes.*?"seq":(.*?),""")
  lastSeq = ((regSeq findAllIn resp)).toString()
  println(lastSeq) //prints non-empty iterator
}
return resp.split( """for\(;;\);""").last.stripPrefix("[").stripSuffix("]").trim
```

}

Comment: [SO] isn't a code writing service.  Please show us what you have tried and where you are stuck. See [mcve]

Comment: I have tried to filter the value using Regex. Even though couldn't filter it.

Comment: Again, show us what you've tried (this means code) and read that [mcve] link. We can't just guess what your problem is.

Comment: It is printing "Non empty iterator. But the regex working fine when I check it in online Regex tester

Comment: `findAllIn` returns a `MatchIterator` because there can be multiple matches. Converting it with `toString` gives thestring "Non empty iterator" since that's what it is - `toString` does not attempt to show its contents. Instead, you want to get the list of matches, presumably, so try `((regSeq findAllIn resp),toList).toString` (or similar, depending on what you need to do with the results). And you need to declare `lastSeq` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks! I have declared `lastSeq` at the top.  I just need to get only the value of  "seq" from the Regex for further calculations. But `toList()` is returning the whole array again.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking but forAllIn will return all matches, and there are multiple matches- since there are two "changes" in your JSON, both of which are followed by "seq" (the first has the other "change" between it and the "seq" but the regex doesnt' stop that. But trying to parse JSON with a regex is never going to work out well. Use one of the numerous JSON reading packages, and read the key/value there in a more structured way.

Comment: I'll check. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with the Regex. I have used JavaScript regex before. Following is giving the required value.

```
def wsResponseToValidJsonString (resp: String): String = {
println ("This is response :" + resp) // prints Response message in JSON format
//get latest seq number
if (resp.contains ("seq") ) {
println ("seq contains..")
val regSeq = new Regex (""""seq":\d""")
lastSeq = (regSeq findAllIn resp).mkString;
println ("Last Sequence :" + lastSeq)//print required value}
return resp.split ("""for\(;;\);""").last.stripPrefix ("[").stripSuffix ("]").trim
```

}

Comment: Please use better formatting and tabbing for clarity.